# MPU6050 with Arduino I2C Unreliable with Motor Noise

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, i2c, mpu6050

I have an autonomous wall-tracking robot that uses relative angle changes from a I2C-connected MPU6050 module along with ultrasonic 'ping' sensors for motor speed control to acquire and then track a specific wall offset distance.  The problem I'm having is that occasionally the MPU6U050's DMP module will stop loading new data into its FIFO.  This can take 2 minutes or 5 hours, but eventually it will happen.  Here's what I know (or think I know)

- AFAICT, I have to have the motors running to get it to fail.
- Installing bypasses on the motor terminals per Pololu guidance for their D20 metal-geared motors significantly improved the situation (i.e. much longer times between failures), but did not completely solve the problem.
- The Arduino I2C bus and at least part of the MPU6050 appears to remain functional after a failure; at least, I can still call mpu.testConnection() and get a positive response.
- Resetting the mpu, the FIFO, the DMP or any combination thereof does not seem to help. Resetting the Arduino DOES restore MPU6050 functionality (after all the setup stuff, including mpu.Initialize()).

As I write this question, I just had another long-term test fail at a little over 3 hours (198 minutes).

Has anyone else experienced this sort of problem with the MPU6050 in a motor-driven system?  Any ideas about how to really track down the failure mechanism?

TIA,

Frank

Comment: check that the bus cable lengths are short and have the proper pull-ups. i had some long-term i2c problems in a data logger that i worked around with something like `Wire.reset();delay(20);Wire.begin();SYS.fixes++;ina219.begin();`

Comment: I2C Bus length is zero (MPU6050 module plugged directly into UNO header).  I did try resetting the I2C bus with no effect.  Pullups are on the MPU6050 module.